# How to correctly populate Datatable JQuery with ajax rest call

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, datatables, feathersjs

For a school project i am creating an API and wanted to implement Jquery Datatables. I'm still quite new to JavaScript so bear with me. I've scanned through a lot of examples on the Datatables.net site but can't quite get the answer i'm looking for.
What i'm trying to achieve is populating a Jquery Datatable with data from a simple API i created.

The html table:

```
<table id="campaignTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>_id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
            <th>_id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>position</th>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

datatables.js:

```
$('#campaignTable').DataTable( {
            "ajax": { 
            "url": "/targets",
            "dataSrc": "data",
        },
             "aoColumns": [

              {"columns": "_id" },
              {"columns": "name" },
              {"columns": "email" },
              {"columns": "position" },
                        ]
                });
});
```

**Output of api route http://localhost:3030/targets:**:

```
{
"total": 4,
"limit": 100,
"skip": 0,
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "577f6e04077321f331d8fbba",
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@email.nl",
        "position": "CEO",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "577f6e08077321f331d8fbbb",
        "name": "test1",
        "email": "test@email.nl",
        "position": "CEO",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "577f6e0b077321f331d8fbbc",
        "name": "test2",
        "email": "test@email.nl",
        "position": "CEO",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "577f6e0d077321f331d8fbbd",
        "name": "test3",
        "email": "test@email.nl",
        "position": "CEO",
        "__v": 0
    }
]

}
```

I am able to populate the table with a simple variable using the same structure, but when using an ajax/rest call it gets a bit difficult. Some other examples suggested that it might had something to do with the output of the JSON from the api. But I don't know how to change that.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What's not good about your post is that once you have reached the issue part, you provided no code. You have tried something about ajax/rest, right? If so, please show us your code and describe what issues do you have.

Comment: What version of dataTables are you using? I think aoColumns is deprecated. [This link](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) for Ajax source data on the dataTables website might be useful

Comment: i've used the following js: "//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"

Comment: i've tried the following as well but it doesn't work:
     $('#campaignTable').DataTable( {
    "ajax":{
    "url":"http://localhost:3030/targets",
    "dataSrc": "data",
    } ,
     "columns": [

            {"data": "_id" },
            {"data": "name" },
            {"data": "email" },
            {"data": "position" },
            ]
     });
    });

The problem with the examples on the Datatables.net site is that the ajax call refer to a file. while my API is an endpoint. Or am i missing something here? Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple different problems with your syntax. I'll post the improved js code (as that is the one that needs the main changes) and then explain my changes.

```
$('#campaignTable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "/targets", //One thing is to check is that this is actually the right path
        //You don't need dataSrc if the source is "data", that's default
         "columns": [

          {"data": "_id" },
          {"data": "name" },
          {"data": "email" },
          {"data": "position" },
         ]
});
```

- @Adam is right, `aoColumns` is deprecated (but still functional). You should really be using the `columns` syntax.
- You shouldn't need to specify the `dataSrc` if you're using `"data"` as that is the default setting (but it shouldn't hurt to include it so you don't have to remove that if you don't want to). If you fix all the other things and it still doesn't work, try putting `dataSrc` back in.
- One change you'll *need* to make but that isn't shown in the code snippet is that your HTML table needs to have an empty `<tbody>` tag in it. This is where dataTables will put the data from your table.

If you fix the above issues and your code still doesn't work, then it probably has to do with your Ajax call. Look into the requests being sent (use Fiddler if you're not sure how do to this) and make sure that a GET request is being sent to your `/targets` page and that the proper JSON is being sent back.

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris! i've tried your suggestions and it  seems that the Ajax Call isn't right. a GET is done to targets?_=123456789n instead of targets.This has something to do with jsonCallback? Suggestions said to add the following option "jsonp : false" But that still didn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guys who posted some of the suggestions. The actual code that seemed to work was the following :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({

url: '/targets',
method: 'get',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data){

$('#targetTable').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',  
        buttons: [
            'csv','pdf'
        ],   
        data: data,                         
        columns: [

              {"data": "_id" },
              {"data": "name" },
              {"data": "email" },
              {"data": "position" },
                ]
            }); 
    }
});


});
```

One thing i didn't take into account was the pagination of the JSON response.
I'm using feathersJS at the moment which automatically adds pagination to a REST service, which i removed.